# How to generate SQL tables from ER diagram in Power Designer 15?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, diagram, entity-relationship, powerdesigner

I want to generate Sql tables from ER diagram in Powerdesigner ,but ,I don't know how can i do that?
 Which Tools i should use?

Comment: Choose `Database -> Generate Database` in the menu.. Unless they changed it since version 11..

Comment: it dosen't have Database->Generate Database Menu

Comment: There are different editions of PowerDesigner... DataArchitect / Developer / Studio each as a normal edition and an Enterprise edition... I don't yet know if it makes a big difference but if you add this information to your question it may help to find a solution.

Answer (score 15):

I guess you have a Conceptual Data Model to represent your ER diagram.

You first need to generate a Physical Data Model from it, using `Tools > Generate Physcical Data Model`, picking the specific DBMS you want to use, Microsoft SQL Server 2008, available for PD 15.0 and up.

And then generate the script using `Database > Generate Database` as mentionned in the first comment.

The need to convert the ER diagram into a Physical DAta Model, is that the ER diagram could use some concepts which need to be resolved before going to SQL; and miss some concept specific to the databaase implementation (like performance indexes).

Comment: In PowerDesigner 15.3 it's **Database -> Generate Database**.